# $(window).load works for keyboard input but not button clicks

Tags: javascript

I made a PT calculator based on tutorials I found online. Basically, when you enter your score (i.e., number of push-ups), the calculator immediately displays your performance level.

But this functionality only works when you enter your score using a keyboard. If you click the "up" and "down" arrows in the input textbox, the calculator does not recognize the updated information. I would like the functionality to immediately display performance levels.

```js
    $(window).load(function(){
      
        $('input').keyup(function(){
            var push  = Number($('#A').val()); 
            var sit = Number($('#B').val()); 
            var chin  = Number($('#C').val());
            var min = Number($('#D').val());
            var sec = Number($('#E').val());

            //$('#Score').html(((push + sit + chin)/3) + ((min + sec)/2)); 
            
            //Push Up
            if (push >= 70) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (push <= 69 & push >= 55) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (push <= 54 & push >= 50) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (push <= 49 & push >= 46) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (push <= 45 & push >= 38) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (push <= 37 & push >= 1) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (push == null | push == "") {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "";}
            
            //Sit Up
            if (sit >= 70) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (sit <= 69 & sit >= 47) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (sit <= 46 & sit >= 42) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (sit <= 41 & sit >= 38) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (sit <= 37 & sit >= 23) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (sit <= 22 & sit >= 1) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (sit == null | sit == "") {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "";}
       
            //Chin Up
            if (chin >= 70) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (chin <= 69 & chin >= 11) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (chin <= 10 & chin >= 9) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (chin <= 8 & chin >= 7) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (chin <= 6 & chin >= 5) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (chin <= 4 & chin >= 1) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (chin == null | chin == "") {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "";}
            
        });
        
 });
```

```css
 h1 { margin: 0 10px 25px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 32px; font-family: Arial }
 input { margin: 0 10px 10px 10px; padding: 5px; font-size: 24px; width: 200px }
    label { margin: 0 10px 10px 10px; font-size: 20px; display: block; font-family: Arial }
 span { margin: 0 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 44px; font-family: Arial }
 stat { margin: 0 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->




</head>
<body>

    <label>Enter your endurance scores:</label>
    <input id="A" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Push-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="300"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 300){ this.value = 300; return false; }">
    <stat id="PushUp"></stat><br>
    <input id="B" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Sit-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="300"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 300){ this.value = 300; return false; }">
    <stat id="SitUp"></stat><br>
    <input id="C" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Chin-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="100"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 100){ this.value = 100; return false; }"
        >
    <stat id="ChinUp"></stat><br>
    <br>
    <label>Enter your run time:</label>
    <input id="D"
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Minutes" 
        required="" 
        min="1" 
        max="59"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
        >
        <br>
    <input id="E" 
     type="number" 
     class="form-control formBlock" 
     placeholder="Seconds" 
        required="" 
        min="1" 
        max="59"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
        >
        <br>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're only listening to `keyup`.  You can pass in multiple events with [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Just a quick pointer, you can store the repeated `getElementById` calls by getting the element once the page has loaded so you don't have to re-query every time the event fires.

```js
    $(window).load(function(){

        var pushUpEl = document.getElementById("PushUp");
        var sitUpEl = document.getElementById("SitUp");
        var chinUpEl = document.getElementById("ChinUp");
      
        $('input').on('keyup input', function(){
            var push  = Number($('#A').val()); 
            var sit = Number($('#B').val()); 
            var chin  = Number($('#C').val());
            var min = Number($('#D').val());
            var sec = Number($('#E').val());

            //$('#Score').html(((push + sit + chin)/3) + ((min + sec)/2)); 
            
            //Push Up
            if (push >= 70) {pushUpEl.innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (push <= 69 & push >= 55) {pushUpEl.innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (push <= 54 & push >= 50) {pushUpEl.innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (push <= 49 & push >= 46) {pushUpEl.innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (push <= 45 & push >= 38) {pushUpEl.innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (push <= 37 & push >= 1) {pushUpEl.innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (push == null | push == "") {pushUpEl.innerHTML = "";}
            
            //Sit Up
            if (sit >= 70) {sitUpEl.innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (sit <= 69 & sit >= 47) {sitUpEl.innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (sit <= 46 & sit >= 42) {sitUpEl.innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (sit <= 41 & sit >= 38) {sitUpEl.innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (sit <= 37 & sit >= 23) {sitUpEl.innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (sit <= 22 & sit >= 1) {sitUpEl.innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (sit == null | sit == "") {sitUpEl.innerHTML = "";}
       
            //Chin Up
            if (chin >= 70) {chinUpEl.innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (chin <= 69 & chin >= 11) {chinUpEl.innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (chin <= 10 & chin >= 9) {chinUpEl.innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (chin <= 8 & chin >= 7) {chinUpEl.innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (chin <= 6 & chin >= 5) {chinUpEl.innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (chin <= 4 & chin >= 1) {chinUpEl.innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (chin == null | chin == "") {chinUpEl.innerHTML = "";}
            
        });
        
 });
```

```css
 h1 { margin: 0 10px 25px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 32px; font-family: Arial }
 input { margin: 0 10px 10px 10px; padding: 5px; font-size: 24px; width: 200px }
    label { margin: 0 10px 10px 10px; font-size: 20px; display: block; font-family: Arial }
 span { margin: 0 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 44px; font-family: Arial }
 stat { margin: 0 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->




</head>
<body>

    <label>Enter your endurance scores:</label>
    <input id="A" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Push-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="300"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 300){ this.value = 300; return false; }">
    <stat id="PushUp"></stat><br>
    <input id="B" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Sit-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="300"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 300){ this.value = 300; return false; }">
    <stat id="SitUp"></stat><br>
    <input id="C" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Chin-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="100"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 100){ this.value = 100; return false; }"
        >
    <stat id="ChinUp"></stat><br>
    <br>
    <label>Enter your run time:</label>
    <input id="D"
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Minutes" 
        required="" 
        min="1" 
        max="59"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
        >
        <br>
    <input id="E" 
     type="number" 
     class="form-control formBlock" 
     placeholder="Seconds" 
        required="" 
        min="1" 
        max="59"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
        >
        <br>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code event raise only when `keyup`.
You have to bind `keyup` as well as `text change` event by using `on` method for desire output

```js
$(window).load(function(){
      
        $('input').on('keyup change',function(){
            var push  = Number($('#A').val()); 
            var sit = Number($('#B').val()); 
            var chin  = Number($('#C').val());
            var min = Number($('#D').val());
            var sec = Number($('#E').val());

            //$('#Score').html(((push + sit + chin)/3) + ((min + sec)/2)); 
            
            //Push Up
            if (push >= 70) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (push <= 69 & push >= 55) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (push <= 54 & push >= 50) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (push <= 49 & push >= 46) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (push <= 45 & push >= 38) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (push <= 37 & push >= 1) {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (push == null | push == "") {document.getElementById("PushUp").innerHTML = "";}
            
            //Sit Up
            if (sit >= 70) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (sit <= 69 & sit >= 47) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (sit <= 46 & sit >= 42) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (sit <= 41 & sit >= 38) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (sit <= 37 & sit >= 23) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (sit <= 22 & sit >= 1) {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (sit == null | sit == "") {document.getElementById("SitUp").innerHTML = "";}
       
            //Chin Up
            if (chin >= 70) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Machine";}
            if (chin <= 69 & chin >= 11) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Excellent";}
            if (chin <= 10 & chin >= 9) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Good";}
            if (chin <= 8 & chin >= 7) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Fair";}
            if (chin <= 6 & chin >= 5) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Poor";}
            if (chin <= 4 & chin >= 1) {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "Very Poor";}
            if (chin == null | chin == "") {document.getElementById("ChinUp").innerHTML = "";}
            
        });
        
 });
```

```css
h1 { margin: 0 10px 25px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 32px; font-family: Arial }
 input { margin: 0 10px 10px 10px; padding: 5px; font-size: 24px; width: 200px }
    label { margin: 0 10px 10px 10px; font-size: 20px; display: block; font-family: Arial }
 span { margin: 0 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 44px; font-family: Arial }
 stat { margin: 0 0px 0px 10px; font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->




</head>
<body>

    <label>Enter your endurance scores:</label>
    <input id="A" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Push-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="300"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 300){ this.value = 300; return false; }">
    <stat id="PushUp"></stat><br>
    <input id="B" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Sit-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="300"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 300){ this.value = 300; return false; }">
    <stat id="SitUp"></stat><br>
    <input id="C" 
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Chin-Ups" 
        required=""
        min="1" 
        max="100"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 100){ this.value = 100; return false; }"
        >
    <stat id="ChinUp"></stat><br>
    <br>
    <label>Enter your run time:</label>
    <input id="D"
     type="number" 
        class="form-control formBlock" 
        placeholder="Minutes" 
        required="" 
        min="1" 
        max="59"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
        >
        <br>
    <input id="E" 
     type="number" 
     class="form-control formBlock" 
     placeholder="Seconds" 
        required="" 
        min="1" 
        max="59"
        onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
        >
        <br>


</body>

</html>
```